# Error: Couldn't match expected type Eval [a]' against inferred type()

Tags: haskell

What is this error?

> 1.hs:41:30:
>           Couldn't match expected type `Eval [a]' against inferred type`()

```
module Main where   

import Control.Parallel(par,pseq)   
    import Text.Printf   
    import Control.Exception   
    import System.CPUTime   
    import Data.List   
    import IO   
    import Data.Char   
    import Control.DeepSeq  
    import Control.Parallel.Strategies 

--Calcula o tempo entre o inicio e o fim de rodagem do programa   
    time :: IO t -> IO t   
    time a = do   
        start <- getCPUTime   
        v <- a 
        end   <- getCPUTime   
        let diff = (fromIntegral (end - start)) / (10^12)   
        printf "Computation time: %0.3f sec\n" (diff :: Double)   
        return v   

learquivo :: FilePath -> IO ([[Int]])   
    learquivo s = do    
                conteudo <- readFile s    
                return (read conteudo)    

main :: IO ()   
    main = do    
        t1 <- getCPUTime  
        conteudo <- learquivo "list.txt"  
        let !mapasort = (map qsort conteudo) `using` (parList rdeepseq)  
        t2 <- getCPUTime  
        let difft2t1 = (fromIntegral (t2 -t1)) / (10^12)  
        printf "Computation time %0.3f sec" (difft2t1 :: Double)  

qsort [] = []  
    qsort [x] = [x]  
    qsort (x:xs) =  
`           losort ++ (x:hisort) `using` strategy  `
        where  
            losort = qsort [y|y <- xs, y < x]  
            hisort = qsort [y|y <- xs, y >= x]  
            strategy result = rnf losort `par`  
                        rnf hisort `pseq`  
                        rnf result
```

Comment: I don't have time right now, but try to isolate the problem by creating a file with the definition for `strategy` and whatever dependencies it requires. It may give a better error message.

Comment: Help us out by marking line 41 for us.

Comment: The error is in `losort ++ (x:hisort) ``using`` strategy`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the problem is that you are using `rnf` from the `Control.Deepseq`

```
rnf :: (NFData a) => a -> ()
```

which is coincidentally the strategy in terms of `parallel < 2.2`:

```
type Strategy a = a -> ()   -- strategy type in early parallel package
```

but [since version 2.2](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parallel/2.2.0.0/doc/html/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html) of `parallel`, strategies have a different type:

```
type Strategy a = a -> Eval a
```

P.S. Latest version of `parallel` is 3.1.0.1. You may consider reading [the complete history of API revisions](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parallel/3.1.0.1/doc/html/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html#12). As far as I understand, the latest API version is explained in [Seq no More: Better Strategies for Parallel Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/~simonmar/papers/strategies.pdf) paper.